# google maps geocoder not returning locality

Tags: google-maps

My geocoder used to work fine, but now it only returns the county, state and country. According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), the geocoder should return locality (city).

SEARCHING "Winnetka"...
EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Winnetka",
               "short_name" : "Winnetka",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New Trier",
               "short_name" : "New Trier",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Cook County",
               "short_name" : "Cook County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Illinois",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Winnetka, IL, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.1282269,
                  "lng" : -87.7108162
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.0886089,
                  "lng" : -87.7708629
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.10808340000001,
               "lng" : -87.735895
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.1282269,
                  "lng" : -87.7108162
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.0886089,
                  "lng" : -87.7708629
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJW8Va5TnED4gRY91Ng47qy3Q",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

ACTUAL RESULTS:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New Trier Township",
               "short_name" : "New Trier Township",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Cook County",
               "short_name" : "Cook County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Illinois",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New Trier Township, IL, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.1282269,
                  "lng" : -87.71080979999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.0886089,
                  "lng" : -87.7708629
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.10808340000001,
               "lng" : -87.735895
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.1282269,
                  "lng" : -87.7108162
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.0886089,
                  "lng" : -87.7708629
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJW8Va5TnED4gRY91Ng47qy3Q",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: It returns "Winnetka" in the results I get back (with "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]).

Comment: We are actually having the same issue with city not being returned when geocoding an address.

Comment: geocodezip, would you mind posting your request? i believe you might be using a different version, but I'm not sure yet how to change the version and which version still returns the correct data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am in the same boat as you. The level at which you are searching is not being returned. If you search for a locality, it is missing. If you search for administrative_area_level_1, it is missing.

@geocodezip in another question with the same problem thinks it is server specific. This happens sometimes, usually when google is making a change apparently. It is really hurting me right now though so hopefully it gets resolved soon.

Comment: If this is true, that's like PayPal stopping transactions between $10-$11. It's a dumb quirk that makes me think of switching to MapBox.

Comment: Yes, it is super inconvenient as my app was totally broken because of it. And there is nothing we can do about it. I believe it is true as it was working last night for some people and not others. I have started hearing things about MapBox. What is your opinion on it?

Comment: Is it working for you now? I am back in business. At least for the time being.

Comment: it is working again. MapBox is pretty legit system, though their pricing is hard to get for enterprise plan.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to give it a serious look then. Thanks and glad it is working for you again as well!